# What is this well?

Tags: earthbound

In Earthbound Beginnings, there's a well or something in Magicant. But I just walk over it. I Can't interact with it. See this screenshot:

[image]

What is this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking around on the internet, this well may not have a purpose. However, further down from that well are a [collection of wells](http://walkthrough.starmen.net/earthbound0/crystalcave.php), which one of them leads to the Crystal Caverns.

> After you've seen all there is to see in Magicant, walk into the main area populated with foes and head east. Over a bridge, you'll find a collection of wells. By walking into the one pictured, you'll descend into a cavernous area.

Below is the well that leads to the caverns:

[image]

Looking at an [overall map](http://walkthrough.starmen.net/earthbound0/image/maps/magicant.png), this well is not marked as a point of interest, so it looks to just be cosmetic, or indicative of the wells just below it.